# Controlling the order of component creation in Anglar in Child/Parent relations

Tags: angular, angular-components

I have a component that uses another component as a child.

```
<parent>
  <child (someaction)="doSomething($event)"></child>
</parent>
```

The `someaction` output of the child component used to be an EventEmitter and that worked fine, but since all the logic in the child component is based off events/observables i ended up with something like this in the **child component**:

```
constructor() {
  const someObservable$ = constructObservableFromCrazyLogic();  // Simplified
  someObservable$.pipe(takeUntil(this.destroyed$).subscribe(action => someaction.emit(action);
}
```

Which to me looks stupid. The EventEmitter is just a wrapped Observable and i'm breaking one async flow into a subscription to just emit on another Observable/EventEmitter. I also need to take care of subscribing/unsubscribing.

So i changed the signature of `someaction` on the child component to be an Observable instead of an EventEmitter. If i keep the creation of `someaction` as a field initializer i guess everything works fine. The problem is - i have several output observables and some build on a few of the same underlying events, making it a hot mess unless i can move it to a method for initializing all these fields.

So for simplicity, let's talk about `someaction` again. I move the logic for constructing the field to the constructor - sounds ok if you set aside testing problems for moment. The thing is - for some reason - the parent component does the binding of the property before the constructor is run (after the fields are initialized though), giving me warnins like this:

```
TypeError: You provided 'undefined' where a stream was expected. You can provide an
 Observable, Promise, Array, or Iterable.
```

Mind you - it still works, but a warning  is printet for each field initialized "late" in the constructor. I have a "fix" by create a fake/empty observable in the field initializer and then overwriting them in the constructor, but now i just made it worse - also not even thinking about testing.

I guess what i really want to know (perhaps i could have skipped the explaining part?) is this:

**TL;DR:** Is there a way i can make the constructor of my child component run before the property binding of the parent control kicks in? I tried moving the order of my components in the `declaration` part in the module, but it didn't seem to help. I might be overlooking something simple but i spend so much time already that i figured it was worth a SO post.

Comment: It would make more sense to me to put a `Subject` in a service and inject it into both components. It will be initialized when it is needed, ie. on the first injection. Parent can subscribe to it, and child can fire `next()`. Depends on what you're trying to do though, I can't really tell from the pseudo code.

Comment: @ChrisHamilton that would be the same as doing .emit on an EventEmitter - i will still have to subscribe to my observable to be able to call .next on the Subject

Comment: Isn't the issue that your observable is not initialized in the parent? A service will initialize it when it is injected into the parent. I think the issue is you're creating a dependency loop, where the child is instantiated by the parent, but the parent depends on something instantiated by the child. So you should instead have a common dependency between them. I might be misunderstanding though.

Comment: Reading over the question a few times, I think we'd need more information about what these observables are doing, when they fire, how the parent consumes them etc. to come up with a good alternative to the event emitter. But I think the direct answer to your question is just 'No'. But I mean, if it was already working, it sounds like you might be trying to fix something that's not broken.

Comment: I need the child to not be dependant on the parent - to have its own event that the parent can subscribe to - be it EventEmitters og Observables. I just don't see why it needs to have both an internal observable that it has to subscribe and unsubscribe to/from while emitting on a different EventEmitter or Subject...

Comment: Also the TL;DR question is still valid - even if i could solve this another way. controlling the order of constructor calls should be something i can control in the DI container and i'm pretty sure i can - atleast if i use a factory to create the components...

Comment: Yeah my confusion comes from the fact that I don't know what the 'internal observable' is doing, and why it can't be in a shared service to be accessed by both components.

Comment: @ChrisHamilton i get that. I was trying to keep it simple, but the child components render option elements for a custom drop-down as well as a custom type ahead. I want it to be "dumb" and communicate via properties and events only